# Error: Package: php-mysql-5.4.45-12.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi) Requires: libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)

Tags: mysql, php, centos6

I am trying to install `php-mysql` on my cent-os server and getting this error :

```
[root@Cloud-POC ~]# yum install mysql-libs-5.1
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.excellmedia.net
 * epel: kartolo.sby.datautama.net.id
 * extras: centos.excellmedia.net
 * ius: mirrors.ircam.fr
 * remi: fr2.rpmfind.net
 * remi-safe: fr2.rpmfind.net
 * updates: centos.excellmedia.net
 * webtatic: uk.repo.webtatic.com
No package mysql-libs-5.1 available.
Error: Nothing to do
[root@Cloud-POC ~]# 
[root@Cloud-POC ~]# yum install php-mysql
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.excellmedia.net
 * epel: kartolo.sby.datautama.net.id
 * extras: centos.excellmedia.net
 * ius: mirrors.ircam.fr
 * remi: fr2.rpmfind.net
 * remi-safe: fr2.rpmfind.net
 * updates: centos.excellmedia.net
 * webtatic: uk.repo.webtatic.com
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-mysql.x86_64 0:5.4.45-12.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-pdo(x86-64) = 5.4.45-12.el6.remi for package: php-mysql-5.4.45-12.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit) for package: php-mysql-5.4.45-12.el6.remi.x86_64
Package mysql-libs-5.5.53-1.el6.remi.x86_64 is obsoleted by mysql-community-libs-compat-5.6.34-2.el6.x86_64 which is already installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-mysql.x86_64 0:5.4.45-12.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit) for package: php-mysql-5.4.45-12.el6.remi.x86_64
Package mysql-libs-5.5.53-1.el6.remi.x86_64 is obsoleted by mysql-community-libs-compat-5.6.34-2.el6.x86_64 which is already installed
---> Package php-pdo.x86_64 0:5.4.45-12.el6.remi will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-mysql-5.4.45-12.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.5.52-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.5.53-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
               libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Available: mysql55-libs-5.5.52-1.ius.centos6.x86_64 (ius)
               libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Available: mysql55w-libs-5.5.50-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
               libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Available: mysql55w-libs-5.5.52-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
               libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Available: mysql55w-libs-5.5.53-1.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
               libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Available: mysql56u-libs-5.6.33-1.ius.centos6.x86_64 (ius)
               libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_16)(64bit)
           Available: mysql-libs-5.1.73-7.el6.i686 (base)
               Not found
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: Please add the Reson for Downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Better solution is to install php-mysqlnd which provides the same 3 extensions (mysql, mysqli and pdo_mysql) using the native driver, and without any dependency on libmysqlclient

Please, remind that PHP 5.4 is EOL and unmaintained by the PHP Project.

Comment: Does it work with PHP 7.0 ?

Comment: Yes (and since 5.5, php-mysql package does not exist anymore, only php-mysqlnd, and remind that "mysql" extension doesn't exist for PHP 7, only mysqli and pdo_mysql)